# Can we use macros to statically dispatch on a return type in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, macros, dispatch, static-dispatch

Now we know that dispatch on Clojure Protocols, [strictly speaking, is dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130991/is-it-accurate-to-describe-dispatch-in-clojure-using-a-protocol-as-static).

We see here a fantastic example of [compile-time dispatch](https://cemerick.com/2010/08/03/enhancing-clojures-case-to-evaluate-dispatch-values/) using a macro:

```
(defmacro case+
  "Same as case, but evaluates dispatch values, needed for referring to
   class and def'ed constants as well as java.util.Enum instances."
  [value & clauses]
  (let [clauses (partition 2 2 nil clauses)
        default (when (-> clauses last count (== 1))
                  (last clauses))
        clauses (if default (drop-last clauses) clauses)
        eval-dispatch (fn [d]
                        (if (list? d)
                          (map eval d)
                          (eval d)))]
    `(case ~value
       ~@(concat (->> clauses
                   (map #(-> % first eval-dispatch (list (second %))))
                   (mapcat identity))
           default))))
```

Here [the writer argues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040115/what-are-the-reasons-that-protocols-and-multimethods-in-clojure-are-less-powerfu) that you will never be able to dispatch on return type in Clojure. To me it seems that with a sufficiently powerful macro, you can do anything.

My question is: **Can we use macros to statically dispatch on a return type in Clojure?**

Comment: What does this `case*` macro have to do with the question?

Comment: It produces a construct at compile-time. It is a non-runtime Clojure dispatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you can use macros to build a Clojure DSL with Haskell's type semantics, so yes strictly speaking it's possible.

However, from a practical standpoint, dispatching on return type at compile-type means making this information available and propagating it at compile-time. There's no built-in 'return type' in Clojure (all functions accept a variable number of Object-typed arguments and return an Object), so you'd probably have to roll out your own type system and require large parts of your programs to participate in it (à la [Type Clojure](http://typedclojure.org/)), with the constraint that the type analysis must be available as soon as you use your macro.

The case of `case+`(pun intended) is different because it it doesn't require a type system, it's mostly a matter of evaluation order.